# I cannot run apps on Android emulator in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, emulator, visual-studio-2019, xamarin

After I updated Visual Studio 2019, I cannot run apps on the Xamarin Android emulator anymore; During debug, the apps will show the below error message:

```
Deployment failed

There is not enough storage space on the device to store package
```

[image: Screenshot]

How do I fix this problem and get my apps running in the Android Emulator again?

Comment: The error is right there. There is no space on the device to store the package. Allocate more space to the emulator.

Comment: Thanks. but i'm new to Visual studio. can you help to tell me how to allocate more space to the emulator??

Comment: Check this topic out: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#there-is-not-enough-storage-space-on-the-device-to-deploy-the-package

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me

Comment: There is no enough storage space available in your emulator remove or uninstall some unnecessary applications from your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**From:** [Troubleshooting Tips - Xamarin Microsoft Page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#there-is-not-enough-storage-space-on-the-device-to-deploy-the-package)

> This occurs when you don't start the emulator from within Visual Studio. When starting the emulator outside of Visual Studio, you need to pass the -partition-size 512 options, e.g.
>
> `shell`
>
> `emulator -partition-size 512 -avd MonoDroid`
>
> Ensure you use the correct simulator name, i.e. [the name you used when configuring the simulator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/windows#device).